# How do I do a BaseActivity or something similar so that I only have to do an Internet Connection BroadcastReceiver once?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-databinding

I currently have my own broadcast receiver in every activity, but with 10 or more activities this is really unpleasant. Now my question is:

How do I do a BaseActivity or something similar so that I only have to do an Internet Connection BroadcastReceiver once? Or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Abstract Class extending from AppCompatActivity , And all your activities will extend from this base class from now on and there you can register/unregister your receiver in proper lifecycle methods , and you can also create an abstract method and forcing other activities to implement that.

In every activity what you wanna do when you get notified will on that abstract method implementation, and the you call that from baseActivity when you receive the broadcast.

Or if you are using Kotlin the you can also use DSL to that, that would be kind of cool.

you can create a function variable in Baseactivity, and a method to pass the function -

```
val onInternetConnect : (() -> Unit)? = null

onConnect(block : (() -> Unit)){

onInternetConnect = block

}
```

the on from each Activity **onCreate** you can that like this -

```
onConnect {
Your Code Goes Here
}
```

And from BaseActivity, Invoke it in when you receive the broadcast -

```
onInternetConnect?.invoke()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer. But how exactly do I create a BaseActivity that also has ViewModel and DataBinding?

Comment: Your ViewModel wont be shared ,  the purpose of ViewModel so that it can solve the problems during configuration change and retaining data. ViewModel survives that and live through the full life of the activity, and its different for each activity because it is tied to LifecycleOwners which is your activities or fragments, you can share a viewModel between your activity and fragment but what you are asking its not the way ViewModel works, Why do you want it anyway? perhaps I can suggest you something better if I know the requirement.

Comment: And as I said your BaseActivity would be Abstract so there is no way it can be instantiated and no way of it having a ViewModel.

Comment: But why do I have to call setContentView in the BaseActivity?  Can I not do all this in the normal activity and then do the functions in the BaseActivity, which is the same everywhere? @kaustav07

Comment: yeah you can do both, you can put set contentView on the child activity or if you have some kind of common UI component like a common Header component or something then you can do that in Base..

Comment: Ah okay thank you. I was unsure about that. But if that works, then I can handle it that way. Thanks a lot. @ kaustav07

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you..thank you.. @L30N